# How To access the arrays element that is present inside object by Index or any other possible way in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Basically I was trying to access the properties of an object in JavaScript and than I thought If i can access the array values present inside the object

```
// Object
let user={
  name:"rajat",
  age:23,
  email:["ag.112","ag.113"]
};
```

now for accessing particular elements of an array I am not able to understand how to do this

```
console.log(user);
console.log(user.name);
console.log(user.age);
console.log(user['age']);
```

like I want to access the 2nd element present inside the email(ag.113) In JavaScript

Comment: Try `user.email[1]` for that. Objects are key-value pair, so dot(`.`) makes sence horever, arrays are indexed and hence you will have to use `position` of element where first position is 0

Comment: I have removed the [tag:java] tag. Please note that Java and Javascript are as different as Austria and Australia.

Comment: You can post your comment as an answer It was enough than I can mark it as an answer and thanks for clearing my doubt I just started learning JavaScript @Rajesh

Comment: You need to select property first and then select element which you need (array iteration started from 0) `user.email[1]`

Comment: You can write a simple callback function --> let user={
  name:"rajat",
  age:23,
  email:["ag.112","ag.113"]
};

user.email.forEach(function(arr) {
    console.log(arr);
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if that's what you mean, but you can do :

```
numb = 0/1

user.email[numb]
```

to get the contents of "email";
or you can do

```
user[email][numb]
```

i wrote a simple function to handle those easy and putting them into local Storage:

```js
function getlist(option, name, listid, must, childnam, contenta, contentb) {

    if (list != 1) {
        if (option != "help") {
            var listid = "produkte";
            var list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(listid));



            console.log(list)

            var allleng = _.size(list);



            console.log(cont);
            switch (option) {
                default: var child = list;

                return child;
                break;
                case "get":
                        var child = list[name];

                    return child;
                    break;
                case "pardel":
                        var child = list[name];
                    var leng = _.size(child);
                    var cont = child[childnam];
                    delete list[name];
                    localStorage.setItem(listid, JSON.stringify(list));
                    return list;
                    break;

                case "setpar":

                        list = _.extend(list, _.object([
                        [contenta, {}]
                    ]));
                    localStorage.setItem(listid, JSON.stringify(list));
                    return list;

                    break;
                case "set":

                        list = _.extend(list, _.extend(list[name], _.object([
                        [childnam, contenta],
                        [(childnam + "must"), must]
                    ])));

                    localStorage.setItem(listid, JSON.stringify(list));
                    return list;
                    break;
                case "setchild":

                        list[name] = _.extend(list, _.extend(list[name], _.object([
                        [childnam, _.object([
                            [contenta, contentb],
                            [(contenta + "must"), must]
                        ])]
                    ])));

                    localStorage.setItem(listid, JSON.stringify(list));
                    return list;
                    break;
                case "length":
                        var child = list[name];
                    var leng = _.size(child);
                    var cont = child[childnam];
                    return leng;
                    break;
                case "parlength":
                        var child = list[name];
                    var leng = _.size(child);
                    var cont = child[childnam];
                    return _.size(list);
                    break;
                case "childlength":
                        var child = list[name];
                    var leng = _.size(child);
                    var cont = child[childnam];
                    return _.size(list[name][childnam]);
                    break;
                case "childdel":
                        var child = list[name];
                    var leng = _.size(child);
                    var cont = child[childnam];
                    delete list[name][childnam][contenta];
                    localStorage.setItem(listid, JSON.stringify(list));

                    return list;
                    break;
                case "del":
                        var child = list[name];
                    var leng = _.size(child);
                    var cont = child[childnam];
                    delete list[name][childnam];
                    localStorage.setItem(listid, JSON.stringify(list));

                    return list;
                    break;
                case "getchild":
                        var child = list[name];
                    var leng = _.size(child);
                    var cont = child[childnam];
                    return list[name][childnam];
                    break;
                case "getpar":

                        return list;
                    break;

            }
        } else {
            console.log("getpar: gibt alle Arten an Produkten aus");
            console.log("get: gibt den ersten inhalt aus");
            console.log("getchild:");
            console.log("pardel:");
            console.log("del:");
            console.log("set:");
            console.log("setchild:");
            console.log("setpar:");
            console.log("parlength:");
            console.log("childlength:");
            console.log("length:");
            console.log("help: hilfe!! lasst mich hier raus!!!");
        }


    } else {}
}
```

Comment: I wrote some code to simplify this a while ago if you want to, I could share it to you

Comment: thanks @Dennis Anonymus Minecrafter

Comment: although you will need Underscore.js for it... it's worth installing if you are going to do alot with arrays and Objects